# How can I delete the tag from the tag list of the act_as_taggable plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable

I have tried to destroy tags from the given code but it's not working. How can it be accomplished?

```
 @tag = Tag.find_by_name(params[:name])
  @tag.destroy
  render :update do |page|
    page[:divtag].innerHTML = render :partial => "controls/tag_list"
  end
```

Comment: What is this *act_as_tagg* plugin? Could you provide some more information about it. `@tag.destroy` should delete the tag, so something else must be interfering.

Comment: Heh stumbled accidentally into it: acts-as-taggable-on You'd better change the title of the question

Comment: yes friend ,, its the same one "acts-as-taggable" plugin ,, i got this by taking params name and it show  error like 
" nil can't be coerced into Fixnum "

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The example you provided seems broken. Normally you have a list of tags belonging to a Model (lets say a User model). Then you could call something like this:

```
# Find a user
@user = User.find_by_name("Bobby")
# Show available tags
@user.tag_list # => ["awesome", "slick", "hefty"] as TagList
# Remove the "slick" tag
@user.tag_list.remove("slick")
# Store change
@user.save
```

For more information look at the [acts-as-taggable-on readme](http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) (unfortunately, removing tags is not explained).

Comment: Thanks but i got the ans bu solving it other way,

    @tag = Tag.find_by_name(params[:name])
    @taggings = Tagging.find_all_by_tag_id(@tag.id)
    for tagging in @taggings
      tagging.delete
    end
    @tag.delete
    end
  end

Answer (score 3):

ActsAsTaggableOn doesn't have a good way to do this built in (that I can find). Here's how I did it:

First, find the tags you want to delete. This should be an `Array` or `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation`

If you've implemented `acts_as_tagger`:

`tags = @user.owned_tags.where(name: my_array_of_tag_names)`

If you want to find tags by all owners (or aren't using `acts_as_tagger`):

`tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.where(name: my_array_of_tag_names)`

Then you loop through the tags, find all the taggings and `delete` them, and then finally `delete` the tag. (Note that `destroy` won't work in this case)

```
tags.each do |tag|
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.where(tag_id: tag.id).delete_all
  tag.delete
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in deleting all the tags, you can send `delete_all` to the relation.

**Short example**

```
> resource.grades.delete_all
> resource.reload
> resource.grades
=> []
```

**Long example**

```
> resource.grades
=> [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 336486, name: "Kindergarten", context: nil, sort: 0>,
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 336506, name: "Pre-K", context: nil, sort: 0>]
> resource.grades.delete_all
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM `taggings` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 984643 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Resource' AND `taggings`.`tag_id` IN (336486, 336506) AND (taggings.context = 'grades')
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
=> [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 336486, name: "Kindergarten", context: nil, sort: 0>,
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 336506, name: "Pre-K", context: nil, sort: 0>]
> resource.reload
  Resource Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `resources`.* FROM `resources` WHERE `resources`.`id` = 984643 LIMIT 1
=> #<Resource id: ...>
> resource.grades
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 984643 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Resource' AND (taggings.context = 'grades')
=> []
```